# Adding network to machine deployed by Juju

Tags: juju, maas, openstack

I have a small OpenStack cluster deployed with Juju/MAAS. How can I add an extra network to one of the already deployed machines? Because the cluster is operational I would like to avoid redeploying the machine.

What I want to achieve is for the machine and all its LXCs to have interfaces on the new network, this in order to be able to use the `os-public-network` option on the various OpenStack API charms.

I have been unable to find any documentation on how Juju sets up networks, but this is how I imagine it would work. Let us assume the interface of the new network is `eth2`. Then Juju would:

- Create a bridge interface `br2` and connect `eth2` to it. Add to `/etc/network/interfaces`:

  ```
  auto eth2

  source /etc/network/eth2.config
  ```

  Add to `/etc/network/eth2.config`:

  ```
  iface eth2 inet manual

  auto br2
  iface br2 inet dhcp
    bridge_ports eth0
  ```
- Update templates from LXC in `/var/lib/juju/containers/juju-trusty-lxc-template/lxc.conf` and `/var/lib/lxc/juju-trusty-lxc-template/config` by appending

  ```
  lxc.network.type = veth
  lxc.network.link = br2
  lxc.network.flags = up
  ```
- Do the same thing for existing LXC in `/var/lib/juju/containers/juju-machine-*-lxc-*/lxc.conf` and `/var/lib/lxc/juju-machine-*-lxc-*/config`.

Is this a correct interpretation of how Juju would set things up? Are there other considerations?